# Spring Data Unescape content

Tags: java, spring

I should think this is a question asked many times, but I still didn't manage to find an answer, so here it goes:

Imagine a Java EE application, all of the DB goes through Spring Data. When it comes to user submitted data, all is well and good - escapes for everything. However, I also want to be able to submit new content, with img and anchors and so fort, insert into the database, and have it presented to user non-escaped.

What I'm asking is:
 1. I could uneascape all of the content in a Controller, but it seems like a lot of work, and consumed resources.
 2. Is there a Spring Data setting to have certain queries non-escaped?
 3. Is there a design pattern for this, because it seems like a common issue to me?

Thank you.